# Crystal Report application not able to run on Windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Created application using VS2015 on Windows 10 64 bit system, on this system it works fine, but when i run same application on Windows 7 64 bit machine get an assembly reference exception.

Tried installing CRforVS runtime installer or redist packages but no use.

Can anybody tell me how to resolve this exception.

Thanks,

Comment: Post a print of the error

Comment: When you post the print of the error as suggested above, you should also include where in your project the error is being thrown, and as much of that block of code that is necessary to understand what you are doing.  It may also help if tagged the programming language used in your project (C# or VB).

Comment: While creating object of ReportDocument getting below error: The Type initializer for CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument threw an exception